# Renaming/moving a public file on Firebase Cloud Storage using Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, acl

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects) explains how to rename a file in Firebase Cloud Storage using Node.js. However, it turns out that after renaming a public file, it's not public anymore. Is it possible to make it public while moving it?
When uploading a file, it's possible to set the option `predefinedAcl`. Is there such an option in `move()`?

Answer (score 2):

The [API documentation for move()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#move) says that it is not an atomic operation.  It's actually a combination of `copy()` and `delete()`.  Given that implementation detail, and the lack of any alternatives in the API surface, it looks like your only option is to set the ACL on the destination file after you copy it with the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried `makePublic()` after the `move` promise` resolves. However, it returns `Error: No such object`. Is there any other way to make it public after the `move`?

Comment: Since this is a new problem that deals with new specific code, I suggest posting a new question with the code that's not working the way you expect.  The question needs enough information that any one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's just solved. The issue was with the IAM setting. Thank you for your answer anyway.